# How can I initialize the same Windows Form with different control elements depending on different conditions?

Tags: c#, winforms, initializecomponent

I have been knocking my head over this for a few days now, and I can't seem to come up with a solution.

I'm creating a WinForm as part of an application that will have to use two different kinds of ActiveX controls depending on what peripheral device is available to the system.  More specifically, coding functionality for the live capture of a signature using an Esignature Pad.

Now the form will look and behave exactly the same regardless... however depending on which brand/model of Esignature device is plugged in, a different ActiveX control needs to be embedded and initialized on the form.

I don't want to have to create two different forms since they share most of the functionality.  Is there a way I can pass in the proper control to the form as a parameter? But then how do I properly initialize it without knowing what it is first...

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you thought about using inheritance to solve the problem? Create a form with most of the functionality and then derive one for each control type.

Comment: Anyway you have to know how to read your condition from the device plugged in **initially**, then performing the layout accordingly is simple.

Comment: If the ActiveX controls both derive from a common COM interface then you could probably do it by making use of that.  If they don't use a common COM interface then I think Rob's solution really is the best.